# Kubernetes Ingress - Second Node Port is not responding

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am running K8S cluster on-premise (Nothing in the cloud) with one K8S Master and two worker nodes.

- k8s-master : 192.168.100.100
- worker-node-1 : 192.168.100.101
- worker-node-2 : 192.168.100.102

I used kubernetes / ingress-nginx for routing traffic to my simple App.
These are my pods running on both workers nodes:

```
[root@k8s-master ingress]# kubectl get pods -A -o wide
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default                hello-685445b9db-b7nql                       1/1     Running   0          44m   10.5.2.7          worker-node-2   <none>           <none>
default                hello-685445b9db-ckndn                       1/1     Running   0          44m   10.5.2.6          worker-node-2   <none>           <none>
default                hello-685445b9db-vd6h2                       1/1     Running   0          44m   10.5.1.18         worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
default                ingress-nginx-controller-56c75d774d-p7whv    1/1     Running   1          30h   10.5.1.14         worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-74ff55c5b-s8zss                      1/1     Running   12         16d   10.5.0.27         k8s-master      <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-74ff55c5b-w6rsh                      1/1     Running   12         16d   10.5.0.26         k8s-master      <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-k8s-master                              1/1     Running   12         16d   192.168.100.100   k8s-master      <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-k8s-master                    1/1     Running   12         16d   192.168.100.100   k8s-master      <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-k8s-master           1/1     Running   14         16d   192.168.100.100   k8s-master      <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-76mt8                        1/1     Running   1          30h   192.168.100.102   worker-node-2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-bfnjw                        1/1     Running   10         16d   192.168.100.101   worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-krgzg                        1/1     Running   13         16d   192.168.100.100   k8s-master      <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-6bq6n                             1/1     Running   1          30h   192.168.100.102   worker-node-2   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-df8fn                             1/1     Running   13         16d   192.168.100.100   k8s-master      <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-z8q2z                             1/1     Running   10         16d   192.168.100.101   worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-k8s-master                    1/1     Running   12         16d   192.168.100.100   k8s-master      <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-799cd98cf6-zh8xs   1/1     Running   9          16d   192.168.100.101   worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-74d688b6bc-hvxgm        1/1     Running   10         16d   10.5.1.17         worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
```

And these are the services running on my cluster:

```
[root@k8s-master ingress]# kubectl get svc
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
hello                                NodePort    10.105.236.241   <none>        80:31999/TCP                 30h
ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.110.141.41    <none>        80:30428/TCP,443:32682/TCP   30h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.109.15.31     <none>        443/TCP                      30h
kubernetes                           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      16d
```

And this is the ingress description:

```
[root@k8s-master ingress]# kubectl describe  ingress ingress-hello
Name:             ingress-hello
Namespace:        default
Address:          10.110.141.41
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /hello   hello:80 (10.5.1.18:80,10.5.2.6:80,10.5.2.7:80)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

The issue is when accessing the first node by visiting worker-node-1 IP Address with Ingress Controller Port = **30428**, **http://192.168.100.101:30428**, its working fine with no problems.
While accessing worker-node-2 by visiting IP with same ingress port **30428**, its **NOT RESPONDING** from out side the node and also from inside the node too by accessing the URL: **http://192.168.100.102:30428** .
I also tried executing telnet command (inside the worker node 2), no luck also:

```
[root@worker-node-2 ~]# telnet 192.168.100.102 30428
Trying 192.168.100.102...
```

The most interesting thing is the port is shows up in netstat command, as I am executing this command from inside the Node-2 , showing ingress Port:30428 is in **LISTEN** state:

```
[root@worker-node-2 ~]# netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1284/kubelet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2578/kube-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32682           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2578/kube-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1856/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1020/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1016/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41561         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1284/kubelet
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30428           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2578/kube-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31999           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2578/kube-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      1284/kubelet
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN      2578/kube-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1020/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1016/cupsd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           929/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44997           0.0.0.0:*                           929/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1856/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1856/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1/systemd
```

based on my understanding , all worker node must expose NodePort for "ingress controller" port which=30428??

**Edited:**
I found that **"ingress-nginx-controller-56c75d774d-p7whv"** is deployed only on node-1.
Do I need to make sure that the ingress-nginx controller is running on all nodes? how to achieve that if this statement is true?

Comment: What os your node runs on? Can you try to exec into pod that runs for example on `worker-node-1` and try to reach pod that runs on `worker-node-2`?

Comment: I used "Centos 8" , 3 Hyper V virtual machines (1 master, 2 nodes). Yes, i tried to run exec from one pod (running on node1 and try to ping another pod which located on Node 2) it's NOT reachable. Then , i tired to ping another pod located on same node1, its fine , I reached it.

Comment: This is what I  suspected. This is all related centos8 switching from iptables to nftables. Switching your CNI to calico might be solution as they [added support](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2322) for nft by setting 
`ELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND=NFT`. This will tell calico to use nftables backend

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes, I am currently using flannel. So, I will switch to calico and try it out.

Comment: In my comment above there is an `F` missing. It should be `FELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND=NFT`.

Comment: Thanks @thomas for your comments, I managed to switch CNI to calico with setting the new env you mentioned, all nodes are now talks to each others smoothly.

Comment: Great news! I'll place an answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes networking (kube-proxy to be more specific) uses iptables to control the network connections between pods and nodes. Since Centos 8 uses `nftables` instead  `iptables` this cause networking issues.

Calico in v.3.8.1+ included support for hosts which uses iptables in NFT mode.
The solution is to set `FELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND=NFT` option. This will tell Calico to use nftables backed.

> This parameter controls which variant of iptables binary Felix uses.
> Set this to `Auto` for auto detection of the backend. If a specific
> backend is needed then use `NFT` for hosts using a netfilter backend
> or `Legacy` for others. [Default: `Legacy`]

Please visit this calico page to check how to [configure felix](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/felix/configuration).
For more reading please visit [this github issues](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2322#issuecomment-515239775).