# Kubernetes - Calling Microservice by Service Name

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-dns

I have two Microservices deployed on K8S cluster (Locally on 3 VMs - 1 Master and 2 Worker Nodes):
1- currency-exchange Microservice
2- currency-conversion Microservice

I am trying to call **currency-exchange** Microservice from **currency-conversion** by using service name : 
http:///currency-exchange:8000.

It returns error as below: 
`{"timestamp":"2021-02-17T08:38:25.590+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"currency-exchange executing GET http://currency-exchange:8000/currency-exchange/from/EUR/to/INR","path":"/currency-conversion/from/EUR/to/INR/quantity/10"}`

I am using Kubernetes, CentOS8 using Calico CNI with set FELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND=NFT , based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836764/kubernetes-ingress-second-node-port-is-not-responding) to facilitate POD-TO-POD communications. 
Current services available:

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get svc
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE

currency-conversion                  NodePort    10.106.70.108    <none>        8100:32470/TCP               3h40m

currency-exchange                    NodePort    10.110.232.189   <none>        8000:31776/TCP               3h41m
```

Pods:

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP                NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES

currency-conversion-86d9bc4698-rxdkh        1/1     Running   0          5h45m   192.168.212.125   worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
currency-exchange-c79ff888b-c8sdd           1/1     Running   0          5h44m   192.168.19.160    worker-node-2   <none>           <none>
currency-exchange-c79ff888b-nfqpx           1/1     Running   0          5h44m   192.168.212.65    worker-node-1   <none>           <none>
```

List of CoreDNS Pods available:

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get pods -o wide -n kube-system | grep coredns
coredns-74ff55c5b-9x5qm                    1/1     Running   8          25d   192.168.235.218   k8s-master      <none>           <none>
coredns-74ff55c5b-zkkn7                    1/1     Running   8          25d   192.168.235.220   k8s-master      <none>           <none>
```

List all ENV variables:

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl exec -it currency-conversion-86d9bc4698-rxdkh -- printenv

HOSTNAME=currency-conversion-86d9bc4698-rxdkh
CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_SERVICE_HOST=http://currency-exchange
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_SERVICE_PORT=8000

........
```

nslookup kubernetes.default exec Command :

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl exec -it currency-conversion-86d9bc4698-rxdkh -- nslookup kubernetes.default
    nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default': Try again
command terminated with exit code 1
```

How do people solve such a problem? do they configure/tweak DNS to work properly as service registry ?

Thanks in advance

**EDITED:**

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl describe service currency-conversion
Name:                     currency-conversion
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=currency-conversion
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=currency-conversion
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.106.70.108
IPs:                      10.106.70.108
Port:                     <unset>  8100/TCP
TargetPort:               8100/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32470/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.212.125:8100
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl describe service currency-exchange
Name:                     currency-exchange
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=currency-exchange
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=currency-exchange
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.110.232.189
IPs:                      10.110.232.189
Port:                     <unset>  8000/TCP
TargetPort:               8000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31776/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.19.160:8000,192.168.212.65:8000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I just discovered wrong behavior in all coredns PODS, a lot of timeouts:

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl logs coredns-74ff55c5b-zkkn7 -n kube-system
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6675909625369157619.3582573715596351475. HINFO: read udp 192.168.235.221:59744->192.168.100.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6675909625369157619.3582573715596351475. HINFO: read udp 192.168.235.221:53400->192.168.100.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6675909625369157619.3582573715596351475. HINFO: read udp 192.168.235.221:58465->192.168.100.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6675909625369157619.3582573715596351475. HINFO: read udp 192.168.235.221:58197->192.168.100.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6675909625369157619.3582573715596351475. HINFO: read udp 192.168.235.221:57794->192.168.100.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6675909625369157619.3582573715596351475. HINFO: read udp 192.168.235.221:43345->192.168.100.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6675909625369157619.3582573715596351475. HINFO: read udp 192.168.235.221:57361->192.168.100.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6675909625369157619.3582573715596351475. HINFO: read udp 192.168.235.221:51716->192.168.100.1:53: i/o timeout
```

how can i start trace the problem?

**Extra Details:**

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl exec -i -t currency-conversion-86d9bc4698-rxdkh -- sh
/ # wget http://currency-exchange:8000/currency-exchange/from/EUR/to/INR
wget: bad address 'currency-exchange:8000'
```

Comment: can you post the output of `kubectl describe service` for both the services?

Comment: I added description for both services.

Comment: The error you've got looks more like an issue with application then dns. Can you try to curl the address with -v=1 and provide an outputs?

Comment: Inside the POD, CURL not found. I tried with wget package. I added the result to post. any extra help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you have incorrectly setup your CNI overlay network. I checked your previous question to verify node's ip address and to me it looks that your pod network overlap with your host network:

The Kubernetes  `pod-network-cidr`  is the `IP prefix` for all pods in the Kubernetes cluster. This range must not clash with other networks in your `VPC`

The Kubernetes pod network [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) describes this as well:

> Take care that your Pod network must not overlap with any of the host
> networks: you are likely to see problems if there is any overlap. (If
> you find a collision between your network plugin's preferred Pod
> network and some of your host networks, you should think of a suitable
> CIDR block to use instead, then use that during  `kubeadm init`  with
> `--pod-network-cidr`  and as a replacement in your network plugin's
> YAML).

This is also mentioned in calico instructions when creating a [cluster](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/quickstart#create-a-single-host-kubernetes-cluster):

> **Note**: If 192.168.0.0/16 is already in use within your network you must select a different pod network CIDR, replacing 192.168.0.0/16 in
> the above command.

PS. You can always `wget` curl from [here](https://github.com/moparisthebest/static-curl).

Comment: Thanks @thomas again for helping me. appreciated. I did all things again, reset the cluster with new CIDR. then setup Calico. everything works fine.